# toLocaleString() not working no errors showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add commas to the input to both the value integers and the summary number in the middle. I've added

```
$summaryNumber.toLocaleString();
```

but nothing works. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

here's a fiddle with what I'm working with

https://jsfiddle.net/cmLkbq6e/2/

```
$(function(){
  $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "test",         value : 150000000,  color: "#e65c53" },
    { title: "test", value:  150000000,   color: "#26a3b1" },
    { title: "test",      value:  250000000,   color: "#19818d" },
    { title: "test",        value : 200000000,   color: "#396b7e" },
    { title: "test",        value : 100000000,   color: "#a5a5a5" }
  ]);
});
```

those are the values I'm trying to target

and here's the summary number I'm trying to target

```
var $summaryTitle = $('<p class="' + settings.summaryTitleClass + '">' + settings.summaryTitle + '</p>').appendTo($summary);
var $summaryNumber = $('<p class="' + settings.summaryNumberClass + '"></p>').appendTo($summary).css({opacity: 0});

$summaryNumber.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In the jsFiddle, find the below part of the code and change it,
Here is the updated JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cmLkbq6e/11/

```
Previously,

    function drawDoughnutText(animationDecimal, segmentTotal) {
      $summaryNumber
        .css({opacity: animationDecimal})
        .text((segmentTotal * animationDecimal).toFixed(1));
    }

After Modification,
    function drawDoughnutText(animationDecimal, segmentTotal) {
      $summaryNumber
        .css({opacity: animationDecimal})
        .text((segmentTotal * animationDecimal).toLocaleString());
    }
```

Comment: How come using the variable the way I was doing it wasn't working?

Comment: this is working as expected? $summaryNumber does not contain the value and hence .toLocaleString() will not work on it.

Comment: Ah Okay, so which part of the code contains the value for the numbers used at the beginning of the function? Is it $tip.text(data[order].title + ": " + data[order].value) or is that just outputting the text only?

Comment: In this case, $summaryNumber has the <p> tag without the value, the value(i.e : 849,999,896.357 is getting appended in the function drawDoughnutText() so while appending we need to format it with .toLocaleString()... and Yes you are correct, as you have mentioned "$tip.text(data[order].title + ": " + data[order].value)", when changed to $tip.text(data[order].title + ": " + data[order].value.toLocaleString() + '%')
          .fadeIn(200); will give u comma's in the graph values as well when u hover on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the`$summaryNumber` is object , it is not number

as I checked it in your code it be to

```
  var $summaryNumber = $('<p class="' + settings.summaryNumberClass + '"></p>').appendTo($summary).css({opacity: 0});
```

which mean be an Object so your code is not working,
You should do something like:

```
 afterDrawed : function() {
    var number = parseFloat($('#doughnutChart .doughnutSummaryNumber').html());
     $('#doughnutChart .doughnutSummaryNumber').html(number.toLocaleString());   
    },
```